# how to sample points in 3D in python with origin and normal vector

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, linear-algebra

I have two points p1(x1, y1, z1) and p2(x2, y2, z2) in 3D. And I want to sample points in a circle with radius r that is centered at p1, and the plane which is perpendicular to the vector p2-p1 (so p2-p1 would be the normal vector of that plane). I have the code for sampling in XOY plane using polar system, but suffering on how to generalize to a different normal than (0, 0, 1)

```
rho = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
r = 1
x = np.cos(rho) * r
y = np.sin(rho) * r
z = np.zeros(rho.shape)
```

[Sampled points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssx33.png)

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to define two base vectors in the circle's plane.

The first one is arbitrary vector orthogonal to normal `n = p2-p1`

Choose component of normal with the largest magnitude and component with the second magnitude.

Exchange their values, negate the largest, and make the third component zero (note that dot product of result with normal is zero, so they are othogonal)

For example, if `n.y` is the largest and `n.z` is the second, make

```
v = (0, n.z, -n.y)
```

Then calculate the second base vector using vector product

```
u = n x v
```

Normalize vectors `v` and `u`. Circle points using center point `p1` on vector form:

```
 f(rho) = p1 + r * v * cos(rho) + r * u * sin(rho)
```

or in components:

```
 f.x = p1.x + r * v.x * cos(rho) + r * u.x * sin(rho)
and so on
```

Comment: @Pxxxx96 Is my answer unclear?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! This actually works, but could you please elaborate a bit about the reasoning behind it? E.g., I understand why v is orthogonal to v, and u is also orthogonal to both v and n, but why is v chosen as this specific form, and why does the final f represent the circle?

Comment: We should find some vector that gives zero dot product with n. This approach just gives arbitrary example of creation such vector. `0*nx+ny*nz-nz*ny==0` always, and choosing the largest component for negation provides non-zero vector (if n is non-zero).

Comment: About circle - circle in 3D might be described by such definition. Two unit perpendicular vectors form basis, their combination with sin and cos gives circle - exactly as in 2d with vectors (1,0) and (0,1). If we rotate and shift  basis `origin,(1,0),(0,1)`  into `p1, v, u` - we will get circle in 3d

Comment: If we rotate and shift basis `(0,0.0),(1,0.0),(0,1,0)` to transform it into `p1, v, u`, we will get circle in 3d

Comment: If answer solves your problem, you can acсept it as solution with green mark at the left.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have a vector n and we want to find a circle of points around a center p1 with radius r which are orthogonal to n. Here is a working example with code

```
p1 = np.array([-21.03181359,   4.54876345,  19.26943601])
n = np.array([-0.06592715,  0.00713031, -0.26809672])
n = n / np.linalg.norm(n) # normalise n
r = 0.5


x = np.array([1,0,0]).astype(np.float64) # take a random vector of magnitude 1
x -= x.dot(n) * n / np.linalg.norm(n)**2  # make it orthogonal to n
x /= np.linalg.norm(x)  # normalize

# find first point on circle (x1). 
# currently it has magnitude of 1, so we multiply it by the r
x1 = p1 + (x*r)

# vector from lumen centre to first circle point
p1x1 = x1 - p1

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])


# rotate the vector p1x1 around the axis n with angle theta
circle = []
for theta in range(0,360,6):
    circle_i = np.dot(rotation_matrix(n, np.deg2rad(theta)), p1x1)
    circle.append(circle_i+p1)

ax = axes3d.Axes3D(plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)))
ax.scatter3D(*np.array(circle).T, s=10, c='red')
ax.scatter3D(*p1.T, s=10, c='black')
ax.set_xlabel('X', size=40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', size=40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', size=40)

ax.set_xlim(-19,-22)
ax.set_ylim(2,5)
ax.set_zlim(18,21)
```